# Spyder with opencv autocompletion in editor is not working

Tags: python, opencv, autocomplete, anaconda, spyder

I use Spyder 2.3.9 as part of Anaconda installation. When I import opencv and try to get the autocompletion list in the editor ("Tab" key), nothing appears; However, other modules such as os, sys, time, numpy, scipy works. The autocompletion  works fine in IPython Console. The issue only in the editor and so I can't list cv2 functions or inspect objects

Any idea how to solve that issue?